# Mix touchscreen and non-touch screen monitors in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

Is it possible to have two monitors in Windows 7, one touch screen and the other not?  Obviously you would need a mouse to interact with the non-touch screen, but could you still use the touch features on the screen that supports them?

Comment: very good question! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean do the touch screen features still work on the other machine, the answer is yes.

Past that, you can even see some of the touch screen features on a non touch screen monitor (just not the multi touch features!) For example, on the taskbar, click (without releasing) on any icon and then drag the mouse up, and you will see that it does the same as using your finger and dragging up.